# How to create subcategory under each category in Liferay DXP programmatically?

Tags: java, liferay-7

In my program, we have already created vocabulary and under each vocabulary, we have created categories but I am trying to modify the code such that we can create subcategories under each categories and the subcategory will be unique.

I can add a subcategory under each category using Liferay but not sure how can I add them programmatically? Are there any methods or classes I can use to add them programmatically? Any help or hints would be appreciated

I am using Liferay DXP and Java 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what exactly you need to do as you seam to ask for 2 different things.

To add a category programaticaly you need to get a reference to [AssetCategoryLocalService](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/4072a7e5766d6a5258832d16da9a8811c8f50edd/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/asset/kernel/service/AssetCategoryLocalService.java) and call one of the `addCategory` methods. Here is an example from a [test class](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/65059440dfaf2b8b365a20f99e83e4cdb15478aa/modules/apps/portal-search/portal-search-test/src/testIntegration/java/com/liferay/portal/search/facet/faceted/searcher/test/CategoryFacetTest.java#L107-L109):

```java
AssetCategory assetCategory = assetCategoryLocalService.addCategory(
            TestPropsValues.getUserId(), _group.getGroupId(), title,
            _assetVocabulary.getVocabularyId(), serviceContext);
```

To make sure the names are unique you may use [model listener](http://Model%20Listeners). There is [code sample](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/cf49f54ae44f5306e98171b4a7104b9e0e91a4bf/liferay-workspace/extensions/model-listener) that shows how to do this for `Layout` but you may follow the same approach to create one for `AssetCategory`.

Comment: Hi Milen, Thanks for your answer. Basically I need to categorize and manage some web content and for that, I have list of categories currently in which each category has different content.
But now I need to get content based on the parent category and child sub category.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying you don't want to add new categories programmatically but put apply existing categories to existing content?

Comment: OK, sorry for any unnecessary confusion created.
The basic requirement here is to create a vocabulary and under it, I need to create a category and under each category, I need to create subcategories which should be done programatically. 

The answer above will only able to create a category but I need to know if I can create sub categories in a similar way

Comment: Yep. Use the same API. Note how some `addCategory` methods have `long parentCategoryId` parameter.

Comment: here if I add the parent category Id, how can I add the title, name to the parent category?

Comment: well you have to create ii or find it first, then get the id, then create the child with the parent it.

Answer (score 0):

So As I have found the implementation of it, I would also like to give more details and add a code sample which might be helpful for future readers.

Basically, to add a category first we need to create a category if it already does not exist and it should be associated with vocabulary.

```
AssetVocabulary assetVocabulary=AssetVocabularyLocalServiceUtil.createAssetVocabulary(vocabularyId);
        assetVocabulary.setGroupId(groupId);
        assetVocabulary.setName(vocabularyName);
        assetVocabulary.setTitle(vocabulary, Locale.US);
        assetVocabulary.setCompanyId(companyId);
        AssetVocabularyLocalServiceUtil.updateAssetVocabulary(assetVocabulary);
```

And once the vocabulary is created you can add a category to it like below. In this case it is a parent category.

```
AssetCategory parentCategory= AssetCategoryLocalServiceUtil.createAssetCategory(categoryId);
```

and you can set the details to the categories using its setters as required like setGroupId, setCompanyId etc.,

and once it is created create another category like child category similar to above.

```
AssetCategory childCategory= AssetCategoryLocalServiceUtil.createAssetCategory(categoryId);
```

and add the required setters and then finally get the parent category id like below:

`long catId= parentCategory.getCategoryId();` and set it to the child Category.
like below

`childCategory.setParentCategory(catId);`

and When you run the categories, you will see the Vocabularies-> Categories-> Sub Categories. in Liferay Portal.